# Clementine will not launch

Tags: clementine

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and clementine would not launch. I removed it, downloaded the most recent version, 1.1.1, and reinstalled it. It still does not launch. Please help. Thanks.

Here is the output from launching Clementine from the terminal:

```
11:15:23.701 DEBUG WorkerPool:281      Starting worker 0xb43feb50 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_361262713" 
11:15:23.703 DEBUG WorkerPool:281      Starting worker 0xb43feb50 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_1330952195" 
11:15:23.704 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError(1, "Unable to execute statement", "unsupported file format") 
11:15:23.704 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  "CREATE TABLE directories (
  path TEXT NOT NULL,
  subdirs INTEGER NOT NULL
)" 
11:15:23.704 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap() 
11:15:23.705 ERROR unknown                          Unable to update music library database 
11:15:23.712 INFO  main:46                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_361262713" 
11:15:23.713 INFO  main:46                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_1330952195" 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Are you launching it from the launcher or the terminal? If you open a terminal (control + alt + t) and type clementine, you can paste the output here.

Comment: From the launcher, but here is the output from launching it from the terminal:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following command:

  ```
  rm -rf ~/.config/Clementine
  ```

  This will delete the configuration files of Clementine, which might have some corrupt or inappropriate content. Next time you launch it, clementine would reconfigure itself and would probably work properly.
- Run `clementine` to check.

Comment: THAT WORKED!!!!! Thank you very, very much. Please explain what this did.

Comment: Updated the answer.